# Instagram blocks my company website

Tags: instagram

I own a company in the UK and have created an instagram account for it

https://www.instagram.com/mystreamings/

https://www.mystreamings.com

The problem comes when trying to set my website in my profile, it takes it as spam when it's not, that causes that the stories are taken down as well and I can't link it.

My website is been coded from scratch so I can modify the code in case that it's needed.

I have tried using bitly and linktree, non work and I would rather not use walkarounds when my website is completely legit.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to do what help.instagram.com says but it doesn't help. Tried to contact them and no luck.

Can someone help pointing out what I can do?

Comment: Perhaps  "tv.mystreamingsa.com watch online free" is working against you.  Or maybe movie.mystreamings.com  or even full.mystreamings.com or seasonfull.mystreamings.com or line2.mystreamings.com or mystreamings.com or 
frame2.mystreamings.com or free.mystreamings.com or fullwatch.mystreamings.comor frame4.mystreamings.com or stream.mystreamings.com or view.mystreamings.com or line2.mystreamings.com or fullhd.mystreamings.com or streaming.mystreamings.com etc. etc. etc.  https://help.instagram.com/477434105621119

Comment: could be...I'm not in the position of changing my company name anymore, there should be a way, is not spam

Answer (score 1):

I ran your website through [facebook's address debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and it wouldn't even debug it because it said "**We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please [let us know](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151?additional_content=AejW-atD2MSrb5dO5qnyqgzfRH8lHiKx2PoyGfSeSVHFabJUp3bsbTNY_kVSPo_AJgjGtWpAC21DqMJd4jw5vfIV8xB_FISMqK3f-0n2ycgI8HwCX1yeW6IbrAkzzuOTSmoJh21ZzuawHV5V4tVJJ4AVETnNnIgTBwPNI79o0_Ra70DNKSLfVt2IkOIvI7gjB2RYOQqji_OlpFedQZzL4yvPHF9K6mV3QdEOEtpBBZatBchGtqeE9b_AqXEcPq2wh-pcHXURj7rjNLImqsRHJmCKIdCvV2oPV72tUjbXs31ywZlBU91oLxe37uUTvstsNF3O5-jqSqsp8-kz-zXqDGZo38kBItiI8w09D6ZKRBBpvQ).**"

Something on your website does not match Facebook's community guidelines, and that is why the link is not working on Instagram.

Take a look to see if there is any issue that fits: https://transparency.fb.com/policies/community-standards/

Alternatively, try filling out a [report in this page](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/571927962827151?additional_content=AejW-atD2MSrb5dO5qnyqgzfRH8lHiKx2PoyGfSeSVHFabJUp3bsbTNY_kVSPo_AJgjGtWpAC21DqMJd4jw5vfIV8xB_FISMqK3f-0n2ycgI8HwCX1yeW6IbrAkzzuOTSmoJh21ZzuawHV5V4tVJJ4AVETnNnIgTBwPNI79o0_Ra70DNKSLfVt2IkOIvI7gjB2RYOQqji_OlpFedQZzL4yvPHF9K6mV3QdEOEtpBBZatBchGtqeE9b_AqXEcPq2wh-pcHXURj7rjNLImqsRHJmCKIdCvV2oPV72tUjbXs31ywZlBU91oLxe37uUTvstsNF3O5-jqSqsp8-kz-zXqDGZo38kBItiI8w09D6ZKRBBpvQ) to tell them why they are wrong. That was the link in their error message.

More info on this page: https://www.socialpros.co/instagram-link-in-bio-not-working-fix/

Comment: I've tried everything there...reported that the website is not spam either, but nothing...